# can i use column alias in many positions in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

if i managed to make the folowing view in mysql

```
select id,name,score,total,CALCIT(total - score) as x,(CALCIT(total - score) / total) as per from tblx;
```

the process CALCIT(total - score) is being caculated two times

how to do some thing like this:

```
select id,name,score,total,CALCIT(total - score) as `x`,`x`/total as per from tblx;
```

where CALCIT is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select *, x/total from (
    select id,name,score,total,CALCIT(total - score) as x from tblx; 
) as tblx
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will permit you to use a column alias inside the `ORDER BY, GROUP BY` clauses, but you won't be able to reuse the alias in the `SELECT` list.  If you really needed to do this, having many instances of the calculated value, you can do a self `JOIN` which produces the calculation.

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  score,
  total,
  x,
  x / total AS per
FROM tblx JOIN (
    /* Subquery JOIN which performs the calculation */
    SELECT CALCIT(total - score) AS x FROM tblx xcalc
  ) ON tblx.id = xcalc.id
```

This method may be more performant than redoing the calculation in one `SELECT`, but as with anything, benchmark to find out.

Answer (score 2):

better you can use inner query --

```
select id,
       name,
       score,
       total,
       X,
       X/total as per 
 from (
        select id,
               name,
               score,
               total,
               CALCIT(total - score) as X from tblx
      )
```